# Gevent, Flask app stuck while streaming video until client disconnects

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I'm using gevent and flask to create a streaming app.  I've embedded an `img` element inside the html page and set its `src=/video_feed`

The corresponding flask code is

```
def gen():
    global vc
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    if vc is None:
        vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        _, frame = vc.read()

    while True:        
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        r, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame.tobytes() + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

**The problem:** The streaming works fine but the problem is Flask blocks and refuses to accept new requests until the client disconnects!

This is the code I use to start it with gevent

```
def start_gevent(app_port):
    http_server = WSGIServer(('', app_port), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Here is my app log.

```
::1 - - [2018-04-27 18:02:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1827 0.008464
::1 - - [2018-04-27 18:02:59] "GET /video.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1850 <--streaming starts here
 0.001877 [wxpython.py] OnClose called <-- client disconnect
::1 - - [2018-04-27 18:03:01] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 2951956 2.790426 <-- flask log of the request comes late
::1 - - [2018-04-27 18:03:01] "GET /database.html HTTP/1.1" 200 118 0.003394 <-- client made these requests concurrently, but flask didnt respond, it logs them now
::1 - - [2018-04-27 18:03:01] "GET /database.html HTTP/1.1" 200 118 0.000549
```

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Don't use push method as static file ! The stream must be in a separate process, so the RAM image must be created and forwarded to the incoming users. Also, each device does not support multiple access, e.g. camera etc.

Comment: @dsgdfg didn't get you?  are you saying that `while True` is the blocker?

Comment: In addition, the hardest thing in stream controls is time synchronization.  The last image of this application is used because the user time delays are not standard. The system-side processor and ram swelling will appear if you cannot send the other image before the picture is completed.

Comment: You cannot perform this operation on the server because the server runs on the query-response. Cannot stream server in Web server. Create a stream server and manage it through the Web server.

Comment: `www.myserver.com/live` page create a link with user session `www.myserver.com:1234/unique_user_session_id` . So you need to create an additional streaming server.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `time.sleep(100/1000)` in your generator and it will work